# Office clipboard format

Tags: ms-office, clipboard

If I copy a graph from Excel (2007) and choose Paste Special in another Office app, I see a clipboard format called "Microsoft Office Graphic Object", which allows different customizations than Enhanced Metafiles. How do I create such a clipboard object from my own (C++) app so it gets the first-class treatment from Office app?

It's not so important that the chart data be linked like it is within Office apps -- I just want to offer another graph export option.

ClipSpy reports several binary formats including "Excel 2007 Internal Shape", "Embed Source" and "Art::GVML ClipFormat". I guess these are proprietary and private, but in case anyone knows of docs, please let me know.

Comment: +1. This is a good question about how to build formatted clipboard items manually. I'd like to know the answer myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its actually a zip file (the data begins with PK), if you save the data (using [ClipSpy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/clipboard/clipspy.aspx)) you be able to open it with your [preferred zip program](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Poke inside and you find out that the data is an open XML format [which is not too cryptic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264572.aspx).

Comment: @xan Did you manage to get it working? Would you be able to help point me a direction? I am trying to save excel shapes from clipboard to file then restore it again to clipboard and programmatically paste it back at a later time.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jake I did find the OfficeXML inside, but the vocabulary of objects available there wasn't a good match for my content (that I wanted to export).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the format is [documented in the specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313156.aspx) MS was made to release as part of its anti-trust ruling.

Unfortunately, you'll have to read and try to understand them, they're not pretty.

Comment: I didn't see exactly what I wanted there in skimming a few docs, but the file formats there may useful.