# Copy binary data to clipboard via Javascript

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, clipboarddata

Is it possible to put binary data in the clipboard with a specific data flavor?  Even a subset of browsers with hacks is okay.

In this case, the specific goal is copying an Office object, which is a ZIP file containing XML and other embedded files, with data flavor `GVML` ([Office clipboard format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855165/office-clipboard-format))

The answers I can find indicate text is text is definitely possible. Posts about binary are mostly about images, which is also kind of possible. But I don't see anything about other data flavors.

**UPDATE**

It appears that this may not be possible.  The following code runs in Chrome 51, Firefox 46 and Safari 9.0, and is triggered by a Cmd/Ctrl+C keyboard event.

- Firefox copies only text and html to clipboard
- Chromium copies `<b>Hello binary!</b>` but as data flavor `org.chromium.web-custom-data` and embeds the `custom/binary` in zero-padded hexadecimal in the text.
- Safari copies `<b>Hello binary</b>` as data flavor `dyn.ah62d4rv4gu81k3p2su10e4psqf3hw` and does not include `custom/binary` at all.

`document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello, world!');
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', '<b>Hello, html!</b>');
    e.clipboardData.setData('custom/binary', '<b>Hello, binary!</b>');
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });`

Above code from "Example 1" at https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/

[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

Comment: Sounds like there is something in the works for Chromium. https://www.chromestory.com/2019/12/raw-clipboard-access/